# Javascript Regex Surrounded by Non-Word Characters, Don't Include Surroundings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a piece of regex for Javascript to get each and every match of a list of words, but only when they are surrounded by non-word, non-number characters (Nothing in that would fit into the regex of /a-zA-Z0-9_/).  However, the regex I've come up with thus far does not quite work as I want it to.  It still allows for numbers on the side, and it also is INCLUDING the characters on either side of the word.  Here is the regex I have as of now:

```
new RegExp("(?:^|\\W)(task|end|if|then)(?:\\W|$)", "gm")
```

Here is an example string of what I'd like to use this for:

```
task test()
    if true then
        print "hi"
    end
end
```

What is it I should do instead?  Keep in mind that this is JavaScript, and therefore there is no capability for a lookbehind in the regex.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you're trying to match.

Comment: Please show how you are getting the match - it may be your regex is right but you are using it wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you only want to capture `task`, `end`, `if`, `then` if they occur by themselves, with nothing on either side (whole word, no surrounding numbers). To do this, simply use the `\b` word boundary:

```
\b(task|end|if|then)\b
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/uM3zI6

If this isn't what you meant, please update your question to clarify examples of what you want to match.